# derivative of multiplication of three matrices with a matrix

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

In short, my problem is to compute $\frac{d(X^tAX)}{dX}$; where both $A$ and $X$ are matrices.

I have to maximize a negative-log likelihood function $L$

$$L = \frac{1}{2}\ln(|\Sigma|)+\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^t\Sigma^{-1}\varepsilon;$$

where $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix, $\varepsilon$ is a column vector of residuals (in my case) and $t$ denotes the transponse. The probelm is that $\Sigma$ is a function of other matrices

$$\Sigma = J^tCJ$$

where, both $J$ and $C$ are matrices. The matrix $J$ is again a function of a vector $\lambda$. I have to maximize the function $L$ w.r.t. vector $\lambda$. I tried chain rule to solve this problem as follows

$$\frac{dL}{d\lambda}=0\implies\frac{dJ}{d\lambda}\frac{d\Sigma}{dJ}\frac{dL}{d\Sigma}=0.$$

In the above equation, $\frac{dJ}{d\lambda}$ and $\frac{d\Sigma}{dJ}$ becomes a tensor. So, I am no longer able to write these quantities on paper. Also, taking derivative of $L$ w.r.t. an individual element of $ \lambda$ does not solve the problem. There are few online resources which suggest using $vec$ operator to deal with tensors; but they heavily use Kronecker product etc. which I have not been able to understand very well, because most of the online material is very opaque.

Can someone please point me to the solution? If someone can refer a good text dealing with a similar problem, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, the chain rule can be difficult to use with matrix functions. Instead let's stick with differentials, and change the independent variable as necessary, until we obtain an expression in terms of $d\lambda.\,$ Then in the final step, we can recover the gradient.

For convenience, define some new variable
$$\eqalign{
S &= S^T = \Sigma =J^TCJ \cr
E &= E^T = ee^T \cr
M &= M^T = S^{-1} -S^{-1}ES^{-1} \cr
G &= \frac{\partial J}{\partial\lambda} \cr
}$$
Let's also use a colon to denote the inner/Frobenius product, which is a convenient notation for the matrix trace, $$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$

Now we can write the objective function in terms of these definitions
$$\eqalign{
2L &= \log\det S + E:S^{-1} \cr 
\cr
2\,dL &= d\log\det S + E:dS^{-1} \cr 
 &= d{\rm tr}\log S - E:S^{-1}\,dS\,S^{-1} \cr
 &= (S^{-1} - S^{-1}ES^{-1}):dS \cr 
 &= M:dS \cr 
 &= M:(dJ^T\,CJ + J^TC\,dJ) \cr 
 &= M(CJ)^T:dJ^T + C^TJM:dJ \cr 
 &= (CJM + C^TJM):dJ \cr 
 &= (C+C^T)JM:G\,d\lambda \cr
\cr
\frac{\partial L}{\partial\lambda}
 &= \frac{1}{2}(C+C^T)JM:G \cr 
 &= \frac{1}{2}(C+C^T)\,J\,(\Sigma^{-1}-\Sigma^{-1}ee^T\Sigma^{-1}):\frac{\partial J}{\partial\lambda} \cr
\cr 
}$$
I think that last expression has cast everything back in terms of your original variables.

Note that the rules for rearranging the Frobenius product follow from the properties of the trace. Here is a quick list
$$\eqalign{
A:BC
 &= B^TA:C \cr 
 &= AC^T:B \cr 
 &= BC:A \cr 
 &= (BC)^T:A^T \cr 
}$$

Comment: This is very useful. I just want to add that the term $\frac{dJ}{d\lambda}$ in the last line is still a tensor. However, I don't think it is a problem now because I can think of $\frac{dJ}{d\lambda_{i}}$ instead of $\frac{dJ}{d\lambda}$ where $ \lambda_{i} $ is a scalar.

Comment: Can you also suggest a good reference to understand the matrix calculus?

Comment: You didn't have anything in the question about the functional form of $J(\lambda)$ so I figured that you already knew how to calculate its derivative. As for references, there's Magnus & Neudecker's "Matrix Differential Calculus" which will suggest that you vectorize everything in sight. It is widely used.  Personally, I prefer Hjorungnes' book, "Complex-Valued Matrix Derivatives".

Comment: I thought it would be enough to write that 'matrix $J$ is a function of vector $\lambda$'. I just wanted to confirm if my approach of dealing with each element of $\lambda$ separately is correct?

Answer (score -1):

When you differentiate a matrix wrt a matrix you need a special calculus developed by Neudecker and Pollock (as key names). The solutions are matrices of matrices. For example to differentiate a matrix X wrt X we get In^2 ie the identity matrix of order n squared. To differentiate AX wrt to X the answer is (I @ A) where @ is Kronecker product of matrices. There are many papers on the subject and a few different calculuses. I take the Pollock and Neudecker method as the one to follow. There are mistakes in some of the others.